# Detect if Rails is Running a Site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, nginx, passenger

I am part of a team that manages a public facing cloud platform at my company. We have a large user base running VM's that face the internet. I would like to run an automated scan of our address space and see if anyone is running a Rails app so I can notify them to upgrade their version of Rails to avoid a critical security vulnerability that came out this week.

I've noticed that in some Apache deployments, there is a Passenger Header that is useful:

```
X-Powered-By: Phusion Passenger (mod_rails/mod_rack) 2.0.3
```

However, this is not reliable. I'm wondering if there is a reliable way to detect Rails running behind a web server either with response headers or some kind of a GET / POST that can be definitive. Thanks!

Comment: This could be used as easily by malicious parties to find vulnerable targets, so it's probably not a good idea to make the info public here.

Comment: ... but if this is decided to be left alive, I wonder whether it might make sense migrating it to Server Fault? I'll flag a mod and ask them.

Comment: Don't you have a corporate email address that can target your devs? Some apps deliberately muck around so the server/framework specifically *can't* be detected, precisely to obfuscate sites that might be vulnerable to a particular attack.

Comment: I voted your question down (it's the only downvote I made as member here). I think that at the current time possible answers will do more harm then good. That's not to say, that script kiddies won't find a way, but let's not give them any ideas for time being.

Comment: This is silly, you can look up the actual exploit with examples. I had considered using that code to do a check but it was too invasive.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Every Rails site has:

```
meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param'
```

Or could have a submit button where the `name="commit"`

At least that's what I have consistently seen.

Header responses are not reliable, here are three from various Rails sites:

```
Server:Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu)
Server:nginx
Server: thin 1.4.1 codename Chromeo
```

You know nginx and Thin are popular in the Rails community, but that's not conclusive enough to say there is Rails behind it. You would need to run a script that scrapes the site and looks for the meta-tag above. [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) is a pretty good if your script is going to be in Python. [Mechanize](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/) gem is great if you are going with Ruby.

Comment: There's no need to use anything as heavyweight as Mechanize or BeautifulSoup. A simple HTTP GET for the index page should do it. The problem is all ports have to be covered. If getting the index page doesn't seem comprehensive enough, then a full-blown site crawler will have to walk the pages looking for the meta-tag in order to be thorough.

Answer (score 1):

Most rails apps have a submit button where the `name="commit"`

Answer (score 0):

A Rails app could be running on lots of different ports, depending on the configuration allowed. That, plus the fact that the app might not respond in a way you can recognize, seems like a "sub-optimal" way to find out.

Instead, if you own the hosting, you own the drives and the systems supporting the apps. Why not run a `grep` across the systems, looking for strings matching Rails.

Or search for some of the standard Rails files; Use `find`, or `locate` if you have it running.

Comment: I understand the security concerns but please understand that I'm not asking for an exploit either. I think the best approach would be a multifaceted check. Thanks for the suggestions. I don't have access to my users VM's else this whole would be fairly easy.

Comment: I work at a large hosting site, with scores of VMs. Those VMs are accessible to our site admins for maintenance and support issues, which this need would fall under.

Answer (score 0):

Another default setting of Rails that is commonly left untouched is the name of the main  `/assets/application-<hex hash>.{css,js}` files.

I don't thing that a single reliable way of detecting Rails exists, but by using a combination of the `authenticity_token`, the default assets names and the HTTP headers, you should be able do identify the vast majority of the Rails apps.

The [Wappalyzer](https://github.com/ElbertF/Wappalyzer/blob/master/share/apps.json#L1479) script uses these three criteria and considers that the co-occurrence of two indicates a Rails app.

Answer (score 0):

Wappalyzer is a good option, and (shameless plug) have you looked at [Spotkick](http://www.spotkick.com)?  We're in private beta now, but it's a distributed engine for running open source apps, so you could run Wappalyzer across all of your sites to see what's *probably* running rails.

I do this for banklook.com - I run over about 6800 banks to dig up details about security risks.

Let me know if you want more details or information.